# Updated rows in MYSQL from Table View rows

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I'm stumped.

Let's say I've got a table, '1', with three columns, 'A', 'B', 'C'.  Column 'C' has some NULL values.  Another table, '2', has columns 'A' (that matches table '1') and 'C', where 'C' is complete.

How can I merge the values from table '2' into table '1' in MYSQL?

I've tried, and swore up and down it should work:

```
UPDATE 1  
SET 1.C = 2.C  
FROM 1 JOIN 2  
ON 1.A = 2.A  
WHERE 1.C IS NULL;
```

And clues? hints? ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works:

```
update t1, t2
set t1.c = t2.c
where t1.a = t2.a and t1.c is null;
```

Answer updated based on requirements changed. T2 could be a view, so a join might be a better idea. I don't know much about views, though, so I just moved out of the UPDATE line t2... but I'm not sure if it changes anything.

```
update t1
join t2 on t1.a = t2.a
set t1.c = t2.c
where t1.c is null;
```

Comment: This worked like a CHARM.  Thank you so much.  I must admit though, in the above example 'T2' is actually a Table View.  Would it be possible to do this without that step, using a SELECT from another table perhaps?

Comment: Ok, I've updated my answer to the requirement change. Two things: please, provide all necessary information when asking a question and don't change the questions (probably asking a NEW question will be a better idea). Apart from that, remember to always mark your questions as answered when a valid solution is provided. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha.  I'm pretty new to the site, but I really appreciate your help.  Marked as answered, and will do in the future.

Answer (score 0):

your query is correct but try using `Alias`:

```
UPDATE  `tableNameA` `a`  
SET     `a`.`C` = `b`.`C`  
FROM    `a` INNER JOIN `tableNameB` `b` ON `a`.`A` = `b`.`A`  
WHERE   `a`.`C` IS NULL;
```

I added `backtick` in case some of your fields contains [RESERVED WORD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)